# How to preserve value after stop windows service (C#).

Tags: c#, windows, service

How to preserve value after stop windows service 
For Example:In one method of winows service I have completed operation for 1 April and I want 1st April when I restart windows service in that method so that I can start operation for 2nd April

Comment: So you want to store some *data* in a *base* somewhere? Hmmm I wonder... Seriously though, put it in a file, the registry, a database, a web service, carrier pigeon...

Comment: You have many options to do this. You can store the state in a text file on disk, in a database, in the registry or even a web service on a different machine in order to share this state across computers.

Answer (score 0):

Using the filesystem or any other persistent storage will do. Just make sure that the user the service runs under has the correct privilege to access the permanent storage you choose to use.